# google sheet apps script truncate column value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have the following table:

[image]

I am simply trying to write a Google apps script to insert into column E everything in column B prior to '.Upload'. So in the table column E = `20ba4a5c`.

I think I should be able to use the `split()` function to do that but I'm having some difficulty.

`ss.getRange('E'+lastRow).setFormula('SPLIT(B'+lastRow+'.Upload')[0]');`

Comment: Why are doing this by adding a formula instead of using JavaScript to return the required result?

Comment: Let me know if my answer worked for you or I will modify it.

Answer (score 1):

- You should use [REGEXEXTRACT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en) to build a simple regex in order to
  achieve your goal.
- It is also a better practice to use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#:%7E:text=Template%20literals%20are%20string%20literals,editions%20of%20the%20ES2015%20specification.) when dealing with multiple concatenations.

**Solution:**

Replace:

```
setFormula('SPLIT(B'+lastRow+'.Upload')[0]');
```

with:

```
setFormula( `REGEXEXTRACT(B${lastRow},"^(.*?).Upload")`)
```

**Output:**

[image: Output]